# How to set the focus to an InputText element?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Using the [example from the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0#capture-references-to-elements), I'm trying to programmatically set the focus to an input element.

Unfortunately, the example uses a standard `<input type="text">` whereas I want to use it for an [`InputText` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

The Microsoft example uses an extensions method that takes an `ElementReference`:

```cs
public static Task Focus(this ElementReference elementRef, IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
{
    return jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(
        "exampleJsFunctions.focusElement", 
        elementRef);
}
```

Using an `InputText`, I see no way of obtaining such an `ElementReference`.

Providing my own `Focus()` overload with an `InputText` instead, compiled but showed no visual result. Therefore I'm clueless.

#### My question

How can I programmatically set the focus to an `InputText` element?

Comment: To save a soon-to-be deleted answer that should have been a comment instead, here the comment of [Mihajlo Naumovski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2855167/mihajlo-naumovski): "_Never forget in order to have FocusAsync working in Blazor on HTML element like 'div' you have to assign tabindex to it._".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add `id` parameter to your `InputText` and modify your `Focus` method and JavaScript code.

```cs
public async Task Focus(string elementId)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("exampleJsFunctions.focusElement", elementId);
}
```

```js
focusElement: function (id) {
    const element = document.getElementById(id); 
    element.focus();
}
```

Note: this is more a workaround than a proper solution, but Blazor doesn't seem to support it directly.

Answer (score 38):

In **.NET5** it will be much simpler:

```
<button @onclick="() => textInput.FocusAsync()">Set focus</button>
<input @ref="textInput"/>
@code {
    ElementReference textInput;
}
```

NOTE: this feature was introduced in [.NET5 Preview 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-preview-8/#set-ui-focus-in-blazor-apps) so might change until the final release!

Also worth mentioning that in [.NET5 RC1 JavaScript isolation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-release-candidate-1/#blazor-javascript-isolation-and-object-references) was introduced via **JS Module export/import**. So if you still need to use JS interop do not pollute `window` object.

**Update:** .NET 5 was released and this feature works unchanged.

**Also I have a cool [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Common.JsInterop/) which can do some convenient JS tricks for you e.g.: *focusing previously active element without having a `@ref` to it*. See docs [here](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/JsInterop.md#focus-js-see-demo-app).**

Comment: It seems that you are the owner of the NuGet package you mention. Correct?

Comment: Please state your affiliation with this nuget package https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308002/is-self-promoting-a-product-on-stack-overflow-allowed

Answer (score 35):

For .NET 6 and .NET 7:

In your code, create an InputText variable, either in @code, or behind code:

`private InputText inputTextForFocus;`

In the Blazor `InputText` component, reference that variable:

`<InputText @ref=inputTextForFocus>`

Then, in your code, at the appropriate place, you can access the underlying `Element` of the `InputText` and call `FocusAsync()`.  Note `Element` can be null.

For instance, to set focus on startup:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (inputTextForFocus?.Element != null)
    {
        await inputTextForFocus.Element.Value.FocusAsync();
    }
}
```

Credit where credit is due:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q7cXdylU7k

Comment: I had to add                  if (inputTextForFocus != null)   since on the first call to OnAfterRenderAsync it was null, but on later calls it wasn't.

Comment: Also worked great with InputTextArea control using .Net7 Thanks much!!!

Answer (score 5):

I was able to accomplish this by entering the JavaScript directly in the Host.chtml file (you can also add a .js file like the walkthrough suggests):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.exampleJsFunctions = {
        focusElement: function (element) {
            element.focus();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Next, in an extension file, I've added the extension (NOTE: I renamed `Focus` to `FocusAsync` because of naming standards:

```
public static async Task FocusAsync(this ElementReference elementRef, IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
{
    await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(
        "exampleJsFunctions.focusElement", elementRef);
}
```

Then in the razor page (or component), inject the `IJSRuntime`, Add an `ElementReference` and tie it to the element you want to focus (Note: Method names were changed to abide to naming standards):

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using JsInteropClasses

<input @ref="username" />
<button @onclick="SetFocusAsync">Set focus on username</button>

@code {
    private ElementReference username;

    public async Task SetFocusAsync()
    {
        await username.FocusAsync(JSRuntime);
    }
}
```

Comment: InputText isn't an ElementReference, so this implementation won't work on that.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple way to componentise the solution

Example

```
@page "/"
Enter your name
<input @ref=ReferenceToInputControl />
<AutoFocus Control=ReferenceToInputControl/>

@code {
  ElementReference ReferenceToInputControl;
}
```

And here's the code for .NET 7

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public ElementReference Control { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await Control.FocusAsync();
    }
}
```

If you are in .NET 6 or earlier

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public ElementReference Control { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("BlazorUniversity.setFocus", Control);
    }
}
```

With the following JavaScript referenced in your page.

```
var BlazorUniversity = BlazorUniversity || {};
BlazorUniversity.setFocus = function (element) {
    element.focus();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to set focus on an element the Blazor native way. Here's one:

Create a class that derives from the `InputBase<string>` which is the base class of  `InputText` with the same functionality of InputText. In short, copy  [the code of InputText](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputText.cs) to your newly created class, and add the necessary functionality. Here's the new class: TextBox.cs

```
public class TextBox : InputBase<string>
    {

        private ElementReference InputRef;
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {

            builder.OpenElement(0, "input");
    builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
    builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", CssClass);
    builder.AddAttribute(3, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValue));
    builder.AddAttribute(4, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>
        (this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString));
    builder.AddElementReferenceCapture(5, (value) => {
                InputRef = value; } );


            builder.CloseElement();


    }
        [Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("exampleJsFunctions.focusElement", InputRef);
            }
        }

        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
        {
        result = value;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
        }
        }

   }
```

Place this script at the bottom of the _Host.cshtml file, just below

`<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`

```
<script>

        window.exampleJsFunctions =
        {
            focusElement: function (element) {
               element.focus();
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Things to note:
1. Define an ElementReference variable to hold reference to the input element.
2. In the BuildRenderTree method I've added code to capture a reference to the 
   input element
3. Call the focusElement JavaScript function from the OnAfterRenderAsync method. 
   This is performed only once. Note that I cannot use the OnInitializedAsync 
   method which is executed only once, but the ElementReference variable may 
   contain null.
4. Note that you cannot run any of the forms components without EditForm...

**IMPORTANT**: Pressing Ctrl+F5, when your browser is in a minimized state may interfere with seeing the cursor in the text element.

### Code for usage:

```
<EditForm  Model="@employee" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <TextBox @bind-Value="@employee.Name"/>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Employee employee = new Employee();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnValidSubmit");
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; } = 1;
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Nancy";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i use this one for `InputText`

```
 await txtUsername.Element!.Value.FocusAsync();
```

and this for `input`

```
 await txtUsername.FocusAsync();
```

[#ref](https://gavilan.blog/2021/05/04/blazor-input-elements-reference-asp-net-core-6/#entry-title)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly redundant now .net 5 is out, but if you don't want to hard code an element's Id or derive your own input class, an easy way to achieve this is to just add a CSS class to the element, and then find and set focus to that using getElementsByClassName.

Create a script to contain the helper:

```
var JSHelpers = JSHelpers || {};

JSHelpers.setFocusByCSSClass = function () {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("autofocus");
    if (elems.length == 0)
        return;
    elems[0].focus();
};
```

Create a shared 'AutofocusByCSS' component to handle calling the JS at the right time:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender) JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("JSHelpers.setFocusByCSSClass");
    }
}
```

Then in your page:

```
<InputText @bind-Value="editmodel.someThing" class="form-control autofocus" />

<AutofocusByCSS />
```

Works on anything that boils down to a standard HTML element and makes it easier to change the autofocus target by changing the class name output.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "CSS class." I think you just mean "element class." Element classes can be used in either CSS or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

for .net 8 blazor **SSR** template project just add autofocus attribute to the InputText

```
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputText autofocus @bind-Value="RegisterVm.Email" class="form-control" placeholder />
        <label>Email</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => RegisterVm.Email" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @enet's answer, I inherit from InputBase, however not in a `.razor` file but in a `.cs` file:

```
public abstract class MyInputBase<T> : InputBase<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// If true, this element will be focused when the page loads
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter] public bool Autofocus { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Optional. Sets the id on the input element as well as the for attibute on the label element
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter] public string? ElementId { get; set; }


    [Inject] IJSRuntime? Js { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            if (Autofocus) await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("cs.focusElementById", ElementId);
        }
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ElementId)) ElementId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

And my `.js`:

```
var cs = {

    focusElementById: function (id) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var el = document.getElementById(id);
            if (el) el.focus();
        }, 500);
    }

}
```

Couple notes. One, `MyInputBase<T>` is abstract, which pushes down the `TryParseValue` to my individual implementations of InputText, InputNumber, etc, which inherit `MyInputBase<T>` rather than Microsoft's `InputBase<T>`.

Also, note that I set a `timeout` in the javascript. At least for me, if I don't do that, focusing the element doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

easy

```
@code {
   private ElementReference yourRefID;
}

<button @onclick="async () => await yourRefID.FocusAsync()">Set focus</button>

<input @ref="yourRefID"/>
```

you may need to do a Task.Delay if you are opening a modal prior.

Comment: How does this differ from the other answers here?

Answer (score 1):

There is also this built in Component since .net 6:

`<FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />`

[Announcement](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2021/07/15/aspnet-core-preview-6.aspx)

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)