# Blazor, how can I trigger the enter key event to action a button function?

Tags: blazor, keyboard-events, blazor-webassembly

I was trying the todo-list example from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-a-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I want to add a todo item and instead of pressing the button with a mouse click I want to press the enter key. I'm not happy with using JS like in this solution: [How to set the focus to an InputText element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137973/how-to-set-the-focus-to-an-inputtext-element)
And I try to trigger the method private void Enter(KeyboardEventArgs e) by this line of code:

```html
<button @onclick="AddTodo" @onkeypress="@(e=>Enter(e)" tabindex="0"  >Add todo</button>
```

It didn't work.

```cs
    enter code here
    <input placeholder="Something todo" @bind="newTodo" />
    <button @onclick="AddTodo" @onkeypress="Enter" tabindex="0"  >Add todo</button>

    @code {
        private IList<TodoItem> todos = new List<TodoItem>();
        private string newTodo;
    
        private void AddTodo()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
            {
                todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
                newTodo = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    
        //private void Enter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
            private void Enter()
        {
            //if (e.Key == "Enter")
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
                {
                    todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
                    newTodo = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`onkeypress` is fired only for character keys. `onkeydown` will fire for all keys pressed. I found some explanation of differences between all key events [here](https://forums.asp.net/post/5325313.aspx)

Try it with `onkeydown` and it worked:

```html
<input type="text" @onkeydown="@Enter" />
```

In the event handler you will have to do this (notice that I check for both `Enter` and `NumpadEnter` keys):

```cs
public void Enter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't solve it. onkeydown still doesn't trigger the Enter method

Comment: I just tried it with enter key and works for me, see this screenshot in debug mode: https://i.imgur.com/870rtg8.png Also you will have to add both `Enter` and `NumpadEnter` for both enter keys.

Comment: I think he wants the Enter to trigger in a TextBox, not on the Button.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't realize that I was using a button copied from question, but the event handler will work for both, I will update the answer.

Comment: I used @onkeyup="@Enter" instead to press enter key one time. I also was trying to do something like this: @onkeyup="@ (e=>e.Code=="Enter"?Enter(e))" but it didn't work. Great job. Congratulations, very knowledgeable...

Comment: KeyboardEventArgs dont work fine when using Android.

Comment: It seems to me that @ onkeyup works reliably but @ onkeydown often requires two keypresses to work — maybe that the KeyboardEventArgs is updated between @ onkeydown and @ onkeyup?

Answer (score 38):

If you use an HTML form, it is simple - no looking for keypresses, just let the browser do the work:

```html
<form @onsubmit=Enter>
  <label for="todo">What to do?</label>
  <input id="todo" placeholder="Something todo" @bind="newTodo" />
  <button>Add todo</button>
</form>
<ul>
@foreach(var item in todos)
{
    <li @key=item>@item.Title</li>
}
</ul>
```

```cs
@code {
    private class TodoItem { public string Title { get; set; } }
    private IList<TodoItem> todos = new List<TodoItem>();
    private string newTodo;

    private void Enter()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
        {
            todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
            newTodo = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

You can try it out here: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/wPabvwlv138n6KMN23

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve this by combining the two events

```
<input placeholder="Task Heading" @bind="title" id="todo"  @bind:event="oninput" @onkeydown="@Enter1" />


public async Task Enter1(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("foucusById", "desc");
    }

}
```

Comment: that bind event should be like this: `@bind-value:event="oninput"`

Comment: That bind:event was necessary. Other answers did not have it and at the time of keyboard event handler the bind string value was not updated.

Comment: Don't use onkeydown but  use onkeypress. The former has a problem with Japanese IME, and the latter worked for both English and Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned Umair, you can use:

```
<input type="text" @onkeydown="@Enter" />
```

With handler

```
public void Enter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

but this solution does not cover "Enter press" on mobile device keyboards (tested on my Android). If you use **e.Key** instead of **e.Code**, then it covers also NumPad enter and the mobile device as well

```
public void Enter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == "Enter")// Covers: Enter + NumPad Enter + Mobile keyboard Go to(enter)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Here is a nice web where you can test it: https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html
Just compare the UI Events Key and Code behaviour

Answer (score 0):

These answers work great unless they are nested within an `<EditForm>`. Solutions using `@onkeydown="@Enter"` will also trigger the `<EditForm>` `OnValidSubmit`.

In this case, the best solution I've found is to nest another `<EditForm>` wrapped around the `<input>` and using it's `OnValidSubmit` to detect the enter key.

```
<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidFormSubmit">
    -- SOME OTHER FORM CONTROLS HERE ---
    <EditForm EditContext="_editContext" Context="entercontext" OnValidSubmit="Enter">
        <input type="text" />
    </EditForm>
</EditForm>

private void Enter()
{

}
```

Comment: it's not a good idea to nest HTML form elements. As per specification (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element)  forms do not allow descendants of its type.

Comment: @Sven In a non-blazor environment I can definitely agree with you. But doesn't Blazor provide the `Context` property on each `EditForm` to handle the usual problems with submitting nested forms?  Someone please correct me if I am misunderstood!

Comment: `EditForm` is just a wrapper around HTML `<form>` with some magic.

Comment: you can see live demos of `EditForm` here: https://demos.devexpress.com/blazor/FormValidation - Feel free to look into the generated HTML when pressing F12 in your browser.

Comment: @Sven The *some magic* being the `Context`. I'm not disagreeing with you - it breaks specification. Although, the specification is [controversial amongst the community](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379622/591285). The `Context` properly wires up which models should be validated when the form is submitted and doesn't cause any issues I'm aware of, unless you can point them out?

Answer (score -1):

The browser will already do this if you add the type="submit" attribute to your button.

```html
<button type="submit" @onclick="AddTodo" @onkeypress="Enter" tabindex="0"  >Add todo</button>
```

Comment: This only works if both the textbox and the button are inside the same `<form>` element. As seen Mister Magoo's answer.