# How do I get an event when the user presses enter?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a [DxTextBox](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxTextBox) where the user enters a search phrase. When the user presses the Enter key, I want that to be the same as clicking the **[Search]** button.

This is a Blazor server app (.NET 8) and the control is **not** inside an `EditForm`.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861068/blazor-how-can-i-trigger-the-enter-key-event-to-action-a-button-function). Last time I did this, it required a small JS code to make it work on mobile as well. However, I don't know the compatibility with `DxTextBox`.

Answer (score 3):

> When the user presses the Enter key, I want that to be the same as clicking the [Submit] button.

When you have a button with `type="submit"` inside the EditForm then that is exactly what should happen.

Comment: I'm using a `DxButton` and it is not inside an `EditForm`. This is for a search page with an edit box and the button. For something that simple should I still use an EditForm? Or if not, is there a way to get the Enter key? TIA

Comment: I just re-wrote the question as I went back and looked at the page and I did not use an EditForm. Sorry for getting that wrong.