# Set focus on dynamic generated InputNumber by using @ref

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

- I created a group of `InputNumber` by `foreach`

  ```
  private InputNumber<double?> OnfocusRef; //This should be dynmic but I don't know how!!!
  @foreach(employee in Employees){
  {
   <EditForm Model="employee">

     <InputNumber @bind-Value="employee.Monday" @ref="OnfocusRef" 
      @onfocus=@(() => OnfocusHandler(employee))

     // other inputNumbers with rest days of the week (Tuesday, Wednesday ..) ....
   </EditForm>
  }
  ```
- After rendering the code up, I get  a rows of inputs days for each Employee like this:

[image]

- By using a tab, user can move between input box, if user jump to the next row, I have to save the changes of the previous row because it is a different employee.

  ```
  private FocusedEmployee {get; set;}
  private async Task OnfocusHandler(Employee employee)
  {
   //first lading of the page
   if(FocusedEmployee is null)
   {
     FocusedEmployee  = employee;
   }
   //jump to next row
   else if(FocusedEmployee.Id != employee.Id)
   {
    await UpdateEmployee(FocusedEmployee)
    if(OnfocusRef.Element.HasValue)
     {
      // Problem here!
      await OnfocusRef.Element.Value.FocusAsync();
     }
     else { 
      FocusedEmployee= employee;
     }
   }
  }
  ```
- **My question**: How can I set focus on the first input box of the current Employee after each saving of pre Employee? I have to loop and create a list of `EditForm` and each `EditForm` has a list of InputRadio, my problem with **`@ref` is not any more unique** !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the focus to an InputText element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137973/how-to-set-the-focus-to-an-inputtext-element)

Comment: @Yogi, it doesn't anwer my question becuase I have to loop and create a list of `EditForm` and each `EditForm` has a list of `InputRadio`, my problem with `@ref` is not any more unique !

Comment: I would use a "ViewModel" that included the Employee and an ElementReference - then in the foreach you iterate over the employeevm collection and set the `@ref` to the `employeevm.ref` - passing the employeevm to the OnfocusHandler - this way each employee has a reference to its own dom element

Comment: @MisterMagoo, thanks a lot, I still have one problem that after 2 sec of focusing I lost the focus again :).

Comment: @MisterMagoo, I saw your comment after post my answer. Great minds think alike ;)

Comment: @daniherrera I didn't have the energy to create a working example ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MisterMagoo, I wrote it just as workout. Someday I would like to become a smart hacker like you, but I need gymnastics <3

Comment: @MisterMagoo,@daniherrera , 3 upvote for solution and no vote for question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deal with Refs dynamically:

```
@foreach (var t in PotatosAndReferences)
{
    <input type="text" @key="@t.Potato.Id" @bind="t.Potato.Name" @ref="@t.Ref" />
}
<br>
<button @onclick="_ => GoN(0)">Focus first</button>
<button @onclick="_ => GoN(15)">Focus 16</button>
@code {
    public class Potato
    {
        public int Id {get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set;} = default!;
    }  
    public class PotatoAndReference
    {
        public Potato Potato {get; set;} = default!;
        public ElementReference? Ref {get; set;} = null;
    }
    public List<Potato> Potatos
        = 
        Enumerable.Range(1, 50)
        .Select(i => new Potato() {Id = i, Name = $"Potato {i}"}).ToList();
    public List<PotatoAndReference> PotatosAndReferences = default!;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
        =>
        PotatosAndReferences =
            Potatos
            .Select(p => new PotatoAndReference(){Potato = p}).ToList();
    protected async Task GoN(int n)
        =>
        await PotatosAndReferences.ElementAt(n).Ref!.Value.FocusAsync();    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying to apply your solution but I have a question about `int n` in `GoN(int n)`, What does mean? and from where does come?. Can I use `Potato.Id`?

Comment: Is just a sample to illustrate you can focus the item do you want. I accés by position but you can access by the condition you need.

Comment: I like potatoes  +1