Automatic submit after type the last digit - C#/Blazor
I have a field to input 6 numbers, here's what it looks like:

And I'd like to have the form submitted as soon as the 6th number has been added but I don't know how to use JS and everything seems to be using JS to do this.
Of course, the goal would be to use C# to do this if possible or to be able for the JS code to communicate with the C# code.
So far, the code makes it so that when I click on the inputs, it starts at the first one, and after each number input, it moves onto the next.
But how could I not only submit the form upon entering the last number, but also get these numbers into a variable or a property that could be used in a submit function ?
Every answer I looked for was in JS and I don't understand anything when it's JS. I don't even understand the JS I'm using but it works so far and as bad as I know it is not to fully be in control of your code unfortunately I couldn't find any example in C#.
Here's the code associated to it:
CodeValidation.cs:
<div class="card text-center ">
    <div class="card-body">
        <EditForm Model="Code" OnValidSubmit="@VerifyCode" FormName="one-time-code" class="otc">
            <fieldset>
                <!-- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element -->
                <div>
                    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" value="" inputtype="numeric" autocomplete="one-time-code" id="otc-1" required>
                    <!-- Autocomplete not to put on other input -->
                    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" inputtype="numeric" id="otc-2" required>
                    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" inputtype="numeric" id="otc-3" required>
                    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" inputtype="numeric" id="otc-4" required>
                    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" inputtype="numeric" id="otc-5" required>
                    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" inputtype="numeric" id="otc-6" required>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>



let in1 = document.getElementById('otc-1'),
  ins = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]'),
  splitNumber = function(e) {
    let data = e.data || e.target.value; // Chrome doesn't get the e.data, it's always empty, fallback to value then.
    if (!data) return; // Shouldn't happen, just in case.
    if (data.length === 1) return; // Here is a normal behavior, not a paste action.

    popuNext(e.target, data);
    //for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) { ins[i].value = data[i]; }
  },
  popuNext = function(el, data) {
    el.value = data[0]; // Apply first item to first input
    data = data.substring(1); // remove the first char.
    if (el.nextElementSibling && data.length) {
      // Do the same with the next element and next data
      popuNext(el.nextElementSibling, data);
    }
  };

ins.forEach(function(input) {
  /**
   * Control on keyup to catch what the user intent to do.
   * I could have check for numeric key only here, but I didn't.
   */
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    // Break if Shift, Tab, CMD, Option, Control.
    if (e.keyCode === 16 || e.keyCode == 9 || e.keyCode == 224 || e.keyCode == 18 || e.keyCode == 17) {
      return;
    }

    // On Backspace or left arrow, go to the previous field.
    if ((e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37) && this.previousElementSibling && this.previousElementSibling.tagName === "INPUT") {
      this.previousElementSibling.select();
    } else if (e.keyCode !== 8 && this.nextElementSibling) {
      this.nextElementSibling.select();
    }

    // If the target is populated to quickly, value length can be > 1
    if (e.target.value.length > 1) {
      splitNumber(e);
    }
  });

  /**
   * Better control on Focus
   * - don't allow focus on other field if the first one is empty
   * - don't allow focus on field if the previous one if empty (debatable)
   * - get the focus on the first empty field
   */
  input.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    // If the focus element is the first one, do nothing
    if (this === in1) return;

    // If value of input 1 is empty, focus it.
    if (in1.value == '') {
      in1.focus();
    }

    // If value of a previous input is empty, focus it.
    // To remove if you don't wanna force user respecting the fields order.
    if (this.previousElementSibling.value == '') {
      this.previousElementSibling.focus();
    }
  });
});

/**
 * Handle copy/paste of a big number.
 * It catches the value pasted on the first field and spread it into the inputs.
 */
in1.addEventListener('input', splitNumber);
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form name="one-time-code" class="otc" onsubmit="verifyCode(event)">
      <fieldset>
        <div>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" autocomplete="one-time-code" id="otc-1" required>
          <!-- Autocomplete not to put on other input -->
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-2" required>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-3" required>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-4" required>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-5" required>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-6" required>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>




I see, do you have any direction I could follow to find how to do it ?

FWIW: Your inputs are missing a name property, preventing them from being posted to the backend

@DarkBee The idea is likely to ajax that on submit

Fair enough - But OP made a double question in one "how could I not only submit the form upon entering the last number, but also get these numbers into a variable or a property that could be used in a submit function"

@DarkBee wouldn't the id be enough in this case ? Knowing that it is used in the code to make it do stuff ?

It seems in Blazor, you can use @ref to not have JS, or JavaScript Interop to have a minimal JS. That is not something I am familiar with.

I have simplified the script. It does not handle pasting a number, if you need that the code will be more complex
I am using a delegated event listener


window.addEventListener('load', () => { // now you can place the script anywhere on the page or externally
  const form = document.querySelector('[name=one-time-code]');
  const fieldArray = Array.from(form.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]'));
  const handleInputEvent = (e) => {
    const currentInput = e.target;

    // Move focus to the next field if input is valid
    if (e.type === 'input') {
      const nextInput = currentInput.nextElementSibling;
      if (currentInput.value.length === 1 && nextInput) {
        nextInput.focus();
      }
    }

    // Move focus to the previous field on Backspace
    if (e.type === 'keydown' && e.key === 'Backspace') {
      const prevInput = currentInput.previousElementSibling;
      if (currentInput.value === '' && prevInput) {
        prevInput.focus();
      }
    }

    // Automatically submit if the last field is filled
    if (currentInput === fieldArray[fieldArray.length - 1] && currentInput.value.length === 1) {
      form.requestSubmit(); // use the built-in error handling
    }
  };

  form.addEventListener('input', handleInputEvent);
  form.addEventListener('keydown', handleInputEvent);
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop submission
    const code = fieldArray.map(input => input.value).join('');
    console.log(code); // change this to fetch the controller with the code
    form.reset();
    fieldArray[0].focus(); // focus first field
  });
  fieldArray[0].focus(); // focus first field when loading
});
.otc input[type="number"] {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.otc fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.otc fieldset legend {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.otc {
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form name="one-time-code" class="otc">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Validation code</legend>
        <div>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-1" required>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-2" required>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-3" required>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-4" required>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-5" required>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" id="otc-6" required>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>




Got it. I see, and it seems that C# has the JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("DoSomething", ""); method to access your JS code. In this case, should the C# code call a method inside the code you posted ? Also, when I ran the snippet it worked like my code does, and for that thank you so much, it is a lot more readable than mine lol, but it doesn't submit on the last input and that's what I've been trying to do. Do you know of a way to make this work ?

Ok, I have fixed the script and made it the simplest I could by letting the browser handle the error messages. You will have to tab to the end after an error

I see why the original was more complex, it seems to allow pasting the code into the first field and spread it to the other digits

for some reason it doesn't work in my code now, I used the <form> again instead of the EditForm but it doesn't work

I converted your editform to form because I do not have C#. What does not work? Any errors in the console?

I removed the submit buttons since I no longer need it

No offense, mplungjan, but I believe you are providing the OP a fundamental misconception about how Blazor works.  You can most certainly use C# to handle onchange events.

Ok, Apologies, I would not expect that. Why don't you show how, then @Bennyboy1973? Using @ref?

I see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137973/how-to-set-the-focus-to-an-inputtext-element

No, Blazor actually has built-in event calls for C#.  You only need href if you're trying to call something internal to a component.

So as weird as it sounds, I can't get any JS to work anymore. I tried your code in Firefox and Brave and couldn't get it to work. I know it's local but I don't get why it stopped working.

Very strange.....

Some edits on your code.
First: Add class="validationInput" to inputs.
Second: Change "if" statements to "else if" for code run priority and add "else" for checking if sum of all inputs length is >=6 in "input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e)".
HTML:
<div class="card text-center ">
    <div class="card-body">
        <EditForm Model="Code" OnValidSubmit="@VerifyCode" FormName="one-time-code" class="otc">
            <fieldset>
                <!-- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element -->
                <div>
                    <input class="validationInput" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" value="" inputtype="numeric" autocomplete="one-time-code" id="otc-1" required>
                    <!-- Autocomplete not to put on other input -->
                    <input class="validationInput" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" inputtype="numeric" id="otc-2" required>
                    <input class="validationInput" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" inputtype="numeric" id="otc-3" required>
                    <input class="validationInput" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" inputtype="numeric" id="otc-4" required>
                    <input class="validationInput" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" inputtype="numeric" id="otc-5" required>
                    <input class="validationInput" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" inputtype="numeric" id="otc-6" required>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

JavaScript:
<script>
let in1 = document.getElementById('otc-1'),
  ins = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]'),
  splitNumber = function(e) {
    let data = e.data || e.target.value; // Chrome doesn't get the e.data, it's always empty, fallback to value then.
    if (!data) return; // Shouldn't happen, just in case.
    if (data.length === 1) return; // Here is a normal behavior, not a paste action.

    popuNext(e.target, data);
    //for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) { ins[i].value = data[i]; }
  },
  popuNext = function(el, data) {
    el.value = data[0]; // Apply first item to first input
    data = data.substring(1); // remove the first char.
    if (el.nextElementSibling && data.length) {
      // Do the same with the next element and next data
      popuNext(el.nextElementSibling, data);
    }
  };

ins.forEach(function(input) {
  /**
   * Control on keyup to catch what the user intent to do.
   * I could have check for numeric key only here, but I didn't.
   */
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    // Break if Shift, Tab, CMD, Option, Control.
    if (e.keyCode === 16 || e.keyCode == 9 || e.keyCode == 224 || e.keyCode == 18 || e.keyCode == 17) {
      return;
    }

    // On Backspace or left arrow, go to the previous field.
    else if ((e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37) && this.previousElementSibling && this.previousElementSibling.tagName === "INPUT") {
      this.previousElementSibling.select();
    } else if (e.keyCode !== 8 && this.nextElementSibling) {
      this.nextElementSibling.select();
    }

    // If the target is populated to quickly, value length can be > 1
    else if (e.target.value.length > 1) {
      splitNumber(e);
    }
    
    else {
     let codeDigits=document.getElementsByClassName("validationInput");
     let digitCount=0;
     let theCodeNumber="";
     for(let a=0;a<codeDigits.length;a++){digitCount+=codeDigits[a].value.length;theCodeNumber+=codeDigits[a].value;}
     if(digitCount>=6){alert("last digit typed. Put your code here to submit to server. code is = "+theCodeNumber);}
    }
    
    
  });

  /**
   * Better control on Focus
   * - don't allow focus on other field if the first one is empty
   * - don't allow focus on field if the previous one if empty (debatable)
   * - get the focus on the first empty field
   */
  input.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    // If the focus element is the first one, do nothing
    if (this === in1) return;

    // If value of input 1 is empty, focus it.
    if (in1.value == '') {
      in1.focus();
    }

    // If value of a previous input is empty, focus it.
    // To remove if you don't wanna force user respecting the fields order.
    if (this.previousElementSibling.value == '') {
      this.previousElementSibling.focus();
    }
  });
});

/**
 * Handle copy/paste of a big number.
 * It catches the value pasted on the first field and spread it into the inputs.
 */
in1.addEventListener('input', splitNumber);
</script>


I tried it but for some reason it doesn't work in my code. Like even my code from before doesn't skip to the next number after input anymore. I imagine your code works, but would you know what could be happening right now ? Like it seems the code doesn't even take the JS into account it's weird

If you think JS not working check:

You have to put JS code after HTML code.
Be sure that insert JS code between  tags.
Your browser is not blocking JavaScript.
Copy your code to notepad. First HTML then JS . Then save it as HTML format and open with chrome.
Hope your problem solved.

